# how to use the case statement to get only selected output

Tags: mysql, case, where-clause

where
(ENTRY_MDE like '09%' or ENTRY_MDE like '08%' ) and
(entry mode like '08%' and pin=0)
is not giving me the right results

The above code is not giving me the desired results, can someone try and help me with case statements or anything. Basically my results should have both the entry modes but not when the entry mode is 08 and pin being 1

Comment: Hi i have a column called entry mode 091 and 081 and another column called pin being 0 and 1 . I am trying to exclude entry mode 081 when the pin is 1. However I need to have the entry mode 091 with the pin  being both 0 an 1. How do I do this in sql ?

Answer (score 0):

You are only including rows where entry mode starts 08 and pin is 0.  If you want to exclude rows where the pin is 1 *only* when entry mode starts 08, you need to use the correct logic for that:

```
where (ENTRY_MDE like '09%' or ENTRY_MDE like '08%' ) and
    not (ENTRY_MDE like '08%' and pin=1)
```

or the equivalent:

```
where (ENTRY_MDE like '09%' or ENTRY_MDE like '08%' ) and
    (ENTRY_MDE not like '08%' or pin=0)
```